проблемы с регистрацией аккаунта instgram через запросы
Было тз, сделать регистратор аккаунтов instagram на запросах, сделано. Но почему-то на последнем запросе (где вводим код) почему-то откидывает, что код неверный.
{
   "force_sign_up_code":[
      {
         "message":"That code isn't valid. You can request a new one.",
         "code":"email_code_incorrect"
      }
   ],
   "status":"ok",
   "error_type":"form_validation_error"
}

# Proceed with email verification if account creation attempt is successful
verify_email_data = {'device_id': cookies.get('device_id', ''), 'email': email}
response = await session.post(
    'https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/send_verify_email/',
    data=verify_email_data, cookies=cookies
)

# Wait and Get Confirmation Code
print(response.text)
await asyncio.sleep(15)
confirmation_code = await get_code(email)
if not confirmation_code:
    print("Failed to retrieve confirmation code.")
    return

# Confirm Code
confirm_data = {'code': confirmation_code, 'device_id': cookies.get('device_id', ''), 'email': email}
confirm_response = await session.post(
    'https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/check_confirmation_code/',
    data=confirm_data, cookies=cookies
)
print(123123123123123123123123)
print(confirm_response)
headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-CSRFToken': 'ZB1QLGi0jgHpTTJwxalLbQ',
    'x-instagram-ajax': '1017912114',
    'x-ig-app-id': '936619743392459',
    'x-asbd-id': '129477',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/130.0.0.0',
    'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/emailsignup/',
}
# Final Account Creation
signup_code = confirm_response.json().get('signup_code')
print(confirm_response.json())
final_signup_data = {
    "enc_password": encrypted_password,
    "day": f"{day}",
    "email": email,
    "failed_birthday_year_count": '{}',
    "first_name": first_name,
    "month": f"{month}",
    "username": username,
    "year": f"{year}",
    "client_id": f"{cookies.get('client_id')}",
    "seamless_login_enabled": "1",
    "tos_version": "eu",
    "force_sign_up_code": f'{signup_code}',
    'extra_session_id': cookies.get('extra_session_id')
}
await asyncio.sleep(15)

# Кодируем данные в строку формата application/x-www-form-urlencoded (не помогло)
encoded_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(final_signup_data)

# Отправляем запрос с кодированными данными
response = await session.post(
    'https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/web/accounts/web_create_ajax/',
    data=encoded_data, cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers
)

print(encoded_data)  # Для проверки формата данных
print(response.text)
if response.json().get('account_created') == 'true':
    formatted_cookies = await format_cookies(cookies)
    with open('accounts.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(f'{username}:{password}||{formatted_cookies}|{email}\n')
    print("Final Account Creation:", response.status_code, response.text)
else:
    print('Signup code error:', response)

Я грешил на куки, но уже захардкодил их, и все-равно не помогает. Испольовал нестандартную библиотеку-Stealth_requests, однако вряд-ли проблема в ней, т.к раньше работало. Может кто подсказать, как это пофиксить?
